# IIS WebSockets handler (native C++) doesn't see the Upgrade header

Tags: c++, winapi, iis, websocket, httpmodule

I had this working on a previous computer, but I'm having difficulties getting my native C++ WebSockets module registered and running correctly under IIS 10 on my new Windows 11 Pro computer.

If I open a Telnet session to `localhost 80` and send the following:

```
GET /test3.qws
Host: localhost
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Origin: https://localhost
Sec-WebSocket-Key: Iv8io/9s+lYFgZWcXczP8Q==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: test
```

That does cause IIS to run my module's `OnExecuteRequestHandler()` method.  Unfortunately, when I query for the `HttpHeaderUpgrade` header, it comes back empty.

```
    USHORT cchUpgradeHeader = 0;
    pHttpContext->GetRequest()->GetHeader(HttpHeaderUpgrade, &cchUpgradeHeader);
    CheckIf(0 == cchUpgradeHeader, HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED));
```

If I skip the zero length check and let it continue, it fails later when it tries to obtain the "websockets" named context.

```
    pHttpStoredContext = pHttpContext3->GetNamedContextContainer()->GetNamedContext(IIS_WEBSOCKET);
    CheckIf(NULL == pHttpStoredContext, HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND));
```

So, it's definitely not being processed by IIS as a WebSockets request.

I've also tried connecting to the same resource using JavaScript from Firefox and Edge, but in those tests my module isn't called.  Instead, IIS simply responds with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Date: Fri, 28 Apr 2023 21:09:02 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

I have Visual Studio attached to `w3wp.exe`, so I am watching what happens, but when tested from the web browser, my code isn't called at all.

My module is 32-bit, and it must be mostly registered correctly since it is called from the Telnet test.

```
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
            <add name="ASPClassic" path="*.asp" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="File" />
            <add name="QuadooWebSocket" path="*.qws" verb="*" modules="WebSocketModule32" scriptProcessor="X:\path\ActiveQuadoo.dll" resourceType="File" preCondition="bitness32" />
            ...
```

Earlier in this testing, IIS was complaining about my `qws` file type missing a MIME definition.  I couldn't remember what I used previously, so I registered it as `text/plain`.

Any idea why IIS isn't returning the `Upgrade` header?

Thanks!